# Executing a git-hook after pull --rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, githooks, git-pull

I'd like to have a hook run after doing `git pull --rebase` in order to check if a certain file was changed. Something along the lines of [this](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/7996717) hook.

I initially thought of using the `post-rewrite` hook, however that only works when commits are being rewritten, and won't run when the `pull` operation simply fast-forwards the branch, which is very often.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I ran `strace git pull --rebase` on a local repository, which performed a fast-forward update...

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to b0a60c3302973ca1878d149d61f2f612c8f27fac.
```

...and it looks as if `git` calls the `post-checkout` hook in this case: