# Which single git hook runs after a git pull, git merge and git rebase?

Tags: git, githooks

From what [I can see](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) I need to use both `post-checkout` and `post-merge`.

Is there a single hook that would trigger after new files arrive in (after a pull a merge or a rebase)?

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148206/executing-a-git-hook-after-pull-rebase but that looks like it's only for rebase.

Comment: Since `git pull` can run different second commands, there's no one single hook that you can predict in advance unless you also control which second command `git pull` runs. It's probably better to just run `git fetch`, then run a second command under your own control.

Comment: @torek that sounds like a good answer